# Img path is not found with env=prod in angular

Tags: angular, path

I have an image with a path below.

```
<img class="tooltips" src="../assets/img/questionMark.png" alt="Smiley face" height="17" width="17">
```

It works fine in development enviroment with ng serve. But when i build the code and add it to apache, everything works fine except this image. I think it is about base url. But i couldnt figure out how to fix it..

Index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <base href="./">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
```

Comment: Use `"/"` as `base href` instead of `"./"`

Comment: then i get lots of 404 errors. @RobinDijkhof

Comment: what error you got? image not found?

Comment: yes image not found @ShaileshLadumor.. I actually changed it to ./assets and it works on both sides but i do not know how. Because the correct path is ../